# URL Rewrite for website subjects and eliminate www at the same time

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to perform a url rewrite to accomplish the following:

www.website.com -> website.com

and for a link page

www.website.com/links.php?subject=Awesomeness -> website.com/Awesomeness

At one point I did have the last part working, but adding the www would trip it up.  My current htaccess rewrite area looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ links.php?subject=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform 301 rules before rewrites. Try this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ links.php?subject=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried the code, but now when you type website.com, it show website.com in the address bar, but tries shows links.php with no content.  The default file is index.php.

Comment: It does go to the correct address in that case.  I'm just running into the default redirect of website.com to links.php instead of index.php